# How to call a javascript function after submit Form to Servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I try to make countdown clock, but I can not call a javascript function by `<script type="text/javascript">...</script>` inside `<c:if>...</c:if>`. Can you help me solve this problem or give some solution to make countdown in jsp file?

demo.jsp: countdonw() function not called

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Demo Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="demo" method="POST">
            Time: <input type="text" id="input-time" name="inputTime">
            <input type="submit" value="Start">
        </form>

        <c:if test="${timeRemain!= null}">
                <input type="hidden" id="time-remain" value="${timeRemain}">
                <p>Time Remaining:  <span id="display-time"></span></p> //this line work
                <script  type="text/javascript">
                    countDown();  //not call this function
                </script>
        </c:if>

    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        async function countDown() {
            var timeRemain = document.getElementById("time-remain").value;
            alert(timeRemain);
        }
       
    </script>
</html>
```

demo.java servlet just send `timeRemain` to jsp file.

```java
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
//        processRequest(request, response);
        String inputTime = request.getParameter("inputTime");
        request.setAttribute("timeRemain", Integer.parseInt(inputTime));
        request.getRequestDispatcher("demo.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Calling a JavaScript function after submit doesn't make sense because after a submit the current page will be replaced by the submit response. It seems you mix and match the different execution contexts. The c:if is executed at the server side while rendering the HTML page. The JavaScript funtions are executed at the client side after receiving the response.

Comment: @vanje I want after submitting to the servlet the clock will count down. Can you give me alternative ideas for <c:if>?

Comment: The problem is not the c:if. You should first learn more about the different web technologies. E.g. implement a first version without any JavaScript. Only JSP and Servlets. You can hold the counter value in a session variable. Then a second version as a static HTML only with JavaScript. And a third version combining client and server side with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
         <script  type="text/javascript">   //oustide  <c:if> tag

          var timeRemain = document.getElementById("time-remain").value;
          if(timeRemain.length>0 && timeRemain !== "undefined")
          {
           countDown();
           }
         </script>
```

Note: Better option would be to ***AJAX*** over here

Refer: https://www.javatpoint.com/ajax-tutorial